# How to disable OWA for creating new documents

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, owa

Which WOPI-binding do I need to remove to disable creation of documents using OWA.

Comment: You want to disable only creating new documents and user can edit/view existing files?

Comment: Yes. I would like to remove the popup menu that appears when you click new document to

Answer (score 0):

Recommended approach is to use Custom Action and push it through Feature Receiver

Another option is to edit page and add Script Editor Web Part then hide required elements using

```
jQuery('.ms-cui-ctl-menu').hide();
```

Comment: This is not removing the wopi-binding. What is the custom action supposed to contain. A popup-blocker for OWA?

Is it recommended to use a feature receiver ? I do not agree. I prefer csom.